# how to call method in codeigniter based on parameter that we input

Tags: php, codeigniter

sorry actually im lil bit confused  with what i want to ask.

let me explain.

so, i have three methods that has same parameter and almost same method name.

```
MV_input_detail($user_id, $post)
TV_input_detail($user_id, $post)
PAR_input_detail($user_id, $post)
```

right now, i call them with if else conditional.

```
if($cart_type == 'MV'):
$cart_id = $this->MV_input_detail($user_id, $post ) ;
elseif($cart_type == 'TV'):
$cart_id = $this->TV_input_detail($user_id, $post ) ;
elseif($cart_type == 'PAR'):
$cart_id = $this->PAR_input_detail($user_id, $post ) ;
endif;
```

i want to optimize the code. with one single line.

```
$cart_id = $this->($cart_type."_input_detail") ($user_id, $post ) ;
```

but it cant run the method.
what should i do to fix this?
pls help me.

many thanks return in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly braces to the rescue

```
$cart_id = $this->{$cart_type."_input_detail"}($user_id, $post );
```